# Mapping values in dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, c#-4.0

**Table 1:**

```
ID 
1
2
3 
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

I have to create dropdowns called `MasterID` & `ChildID` out of this `ID` column. `MasterID` & `ChildID` will have `ID` column values based on mapping. Mapping process will be like any values from the `ID` column can be `MasterID` or `ChildID`. But `MasterID` will have unique `ChildID`.

**Note:** While binding `MasterID` and `ChildID` dropdowns it will have `ID` values on pageload. Once mapping starts then the values should come accordingly. Also I have a Add button in my page and once I select values in two dropdowns and add then they will get saved in the DB.

For ex: If I select the `ID` value 1 in `MasterID` and 5 in `ChildID` and add them to DB, then the next time the value 1 from `ID` column can come in `MasterID` dropdown but not in `ChildID`. Also the value 5 from `ID` column is mapped to `ChildID` and saved, where this value should not appear in `MasterID` and `ChildID` dropdowns. Once any value is selected as the `ChildID and saved, then it shouldn't get displayed in`MasterID`or in`ChildID` dropdowns.

Final Output should be like this.

**Table 2:**

```
MasterID    ChildID
   1           5
   2           3
   2           6
   4           7
   4           8
   9           0
```

Can anyone help me or suggest how I can achieve this for asp.net web application.

Comment: what you have done? show us some part of your code.

Comment: I haven't done any codes. I can bind the dropdown values from DB. But I am stuck up with the mapping and restricting the values to MasterID and ChildID.

Comment: you need the master id to be there after mapping it to the child id. but child id should not be there in the drop down after mapping. am i right?

Comment: It is really not clear what exactly is expected. If a value is selected as the ChildID and saved, your are saying it should not appear in either of the dropdowns. So what should appear in those drop downs? How many IDs are we talking about here? Are these IDs generated in the DB or in your .net app?

Comment: @Jegadeesh - yes after mapping child code shouldn't apperar in any of the dropdowns.

Comment: @Nilesh - The ID's are coming from ID column that is Table 1. After saving the remaining values from ID column should appear in the dropdown.

Comment: Ok I get first point that the IDs are coming from ID column in Table 1. So where are these IDs stored? are they stored in some other table? If thats the case you can easily get the IDs from Table1 and Table2 in two different arrays and then just use a LINQ to selected Ids which are not there in Array2. I will post an example of this as answer, which might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ to filter the values that you need to display in both the dropdowns.
Something like following.

```
int[] table1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
int[] tableMaster = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 9 };
int[] tableChild = (from t in table1
                    where !tableMaster.Contains(t)
                    select t).ToArray();
```

Note: This is just an example so that you get an idea.

[image: Sample console output]